# Работа по нейронным сетям на Java - реалистично ли? Нужен совет от специалистов

Tags: java, нейронные-сети

У меня тема магистерской работы "Разработка системы прогнозирования здоровья на основе нейронных сетей"

Все говорят, что это на питоне делается работа, но я активно изучаю java, и не хотелось переходить на другой язык.

Не подскажите на языке java можно ли выполнить эту задачу или всё таки замучаюсь и лучше на питоне попробовать?

Пишу первый раз тут и может, что то не так делаю), прошу дать знать тогда.

Comment: Кроме написанного ответа, изменил ещё заглавие и чуть переставил акценты в тексте. Cначала должна идти суть:-)

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-ai#neural-networks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Абакар, если вы собираетесь все библиотеки писать самостоятельно, то язык подойдёт почти любой:-)

Так как вряд ли вы это делать будете, то вам надо понимать, какие библиотеки вы будете использовать. Большинство из них - на Python, но что-то должно быть и на java (наверное, точно не знаю).

Учитывая, что для подобных задач пишется (для бакалаврских / магистерских) на достаточно базовом уровне Python, то проще всё же на Python - он на этом уровне значительно проще С-подобного Java (но есть некоторые сюрпризы). Я бы советовал посмотреть его синтаксис и попробовать начать на нем писать. Будет ещё язык для резюме:-)

Чтобы принять решение:

1. Погуглите (это было желательно сдедать ещё до размещения тут вопроса).
2. Обсудите с вашим руководителем (хотя он может и не знать, если сам не пишет ничего и работает на более высоком концептуальном уровне, а идеи студенты проверяют).

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)